# Data Engineering: Parse binary data stream with schema and variable length fields

Tags: parsing, schema, distributed-computing, binary-data, variable-length

I have a data pipeline that receives data from multiple sources, one of which streams binary data in a known schema, with one field being of variable length.

I need to parse this data into a tabular format I can work with later (probably parquet) and I couldn't find any efficient solution for my problem, since I want to properly utilize my cluster to do so (otherwise it will be very slow).

My current solution uses Apache Spark, but it is inefficient because this is clearly not the use case of Spark.

Does anyone know of a framework built for these types of cases?

Answer (score 0):

I have been through a similar problem statement where the I/P data (Streaming Data) comes as Binary Data into AWS Kinesis.

Approach 1:

1. Data is PUSHED into Kinesis via some client.
2. Spark Streaming consume kinesis and DECODE the Binary data from a variety of decoders like base64Decoder etc etc and put it into S3 as the format being DELTA. (Delta format is basically Parquet)

Approach 2 :

1. Data is PUSHED into Kinesis via some client.
2. Instead of Kinesis , enable Kinesis FireHose. FireHose allows you to basically run Lambda functions on top of the kinesis payload + AWS Glue Data Catalo to further define a schema for the incoming data.

Sample Lambda Code -

```
import json
import base64

def lambda_handler(event,context):
  output=[]
  for record in event['records']:
    payLoad = base64.b64decode(record[`data`])
    print(payLoad)

  output_record = {
                    'recorddId':record['recordId'],
                    'partitionKey':record['kinesisRecordMetadadata']['partitionKey'],
                    'data':record['data'],
                    'result':'Ok'}

  output.append(output_record)
  print(output)
  return {'record':output}
```

Sample Output of this Lambda Function will be like - (Full O/p is hidden)

[image]

Post this, I had also configured my AWS Glue catalog schema according to my need.

Do let me know if these solutions help you or maybe we can discuss about your problem in even greater detail.

Comment: Nice, these are great solutions and great directions. With that said I am using Kafka, are you familiar with similar techniques with Kafka?